# Cannot build dockerfile due to port restrictions

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, alpine-linux, docker-build

I am on enterprise internet. We can only use certain ports/connect via a proxy.

I am trying to run the following simple docker command:

```
docker build -t MY_USERNAME/myfirstapp .
```

My dockerfile contains this :

```
# our base image
FROM alpine:3.5

# Install python and pip
**RUN apk add --update py2-pip**

# install Python modules needed by the Python app
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# copy files required for the app to run
COPY app.py /usr/src/app/
COPY templates/index.html /usr/src/app/templates/

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 5000

# run the application
CMD ["python", "/usr/src/app/app.py"]
```

It fails on `RUN apk add --update py2-pip` with the error

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.c51f8f92.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

I can tell from curling this address that it works, so this must be a proxy/port issue.

How can I make this execute respecting my port/proxy restrictions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker build --network=host -t MY_USERNAME/myfirstapp .
```

works :).

Answer (score 0):

You might use the proxy setting like

`docker build --build-arg http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:y --build-arg https_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:y -t MY_USERNAME/myfirstapp .`

I always recommend using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) since this is a standardised way to define build args or for running the container, mapping volumes, ports, etc.
In docker-compose.yaml, the proxy definition would look like the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  main:
    build:
        context: .
        args:
            - http_proxy
            - https_proxy
            - no_proxy
    image: MY_USERNAME/myfirstapp
```

With this configuration, you will pass through the definitions of the three proxy settings defined on your host system.
Calling docker-compose is easy with `docker-compose build` inside the directory where the docker-compose.yaml is residing.